# g2o_viewer was unable to start (0xc000007b)

Tags: g2o

I built the g2o library on Windows 7 with

- Qt 5.6
- Eigen 3.3.4
- libQGLViewer-2.7.1.

Everything compiles fine, but on the first run of g2o_viewer the program complains about the missing QGLViewer2.dll. Therefore, I added it to the directory.

After the second start, I get the application error from the title...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One must add:

- Qt5Core.dll
- Qt5Gui.dll
- Qt5Widgets.dll
- Qt5Xml.dll

Comment: Hey could you share where to add the dll files? I just can't get g2opy to run even after installing all 3.

Comment: @RaunakS simply in the same folder as the exe.